# Search multiple columns and return first row of column (header) if found

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

My goal is to get the header (first row in another sheet) if the value is found in the column.

Because `VLOOKUP` and `HLOOKUP` have some issues (e.g. search criteria has to be in the first column of the matrix), I have to find some alternatives. For `VLOOKUP` I'm using `INDEX` together with `MATCH`. Now I'm searching for an alternative for `HLOOKUP`. I found [this post](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-find-column-containing-a-value), but can't get it working.

I have two sheets:

**column**

```
Car        Living        Boat
----------------------------------
Kia        appartment    Jet-Ski
Chevrolet  house         speedboat
Ford       condominium   Yacht
Audi
```

**search column**

*Original formula*:

```
=INDEX(column!A1:C1;;MIN(WENN(column!A1:C5="speedboat";SPALTE(column!A:C))))
```

*Converted formula*:

```
=INDEX(column!A1:C1,,MIN(IF(column!A1:C5="speedboat",COLUMN(column!A:C))))
```

Currently the result of the above formula is *Car*. If I use the evaluate formula tool I can see, that the `IF` clause isn't evaluating the whole matrix, but I don't know why. What I'm doing wrong?

How can I get the header of the column?

Comment: Try to enter it through holding ctrl+shift+enter as this is an array formula

Comment: @JvdV: Seems to work much better. Can I copy/extend the formula like always or do I have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> for every line?

Comment: You can just drag it, but you probably want absolute cell references before doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using an array formula that needs to be confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>. You need to only do that once, and you are able to drag the formula.

If you don't want to enter through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, an alternative to your formula could be:

```
=INDEX(column!A1:C1,SUMPRODUCT((column!A2:C5="speedboat")*(COLUMN(A2:C5))))
```

Or maybe even better:

```
=INDEX(column!A1:C1,MAX(INDEX((column!A2:C5="speedboat")*(COLUMN(A2:C5)),)))
```